# Rotate Ticks ( I was wondering if I could rotate the tick 90 degree without frame)

Tags: plotting, ticks

I was wondering if I could rotate the tick 90 degrees without a frame
I appreciate any help because it is worth a lot

```
 data = {{0.3451, 0}, {3.61504, 12.6543915693412}, {6.43385, 
   24.4660557294258}, {8.20271, 31.1907823751683}, {10.36884, 
   34.8344756145331}, {12.70524, 35.421243469384}, {14.6349, 
   42.8874481731851}, {16.64968, 41.0755505758374}, {18.57934, 
   46.671633251883}, {20.42387, 52.3446235520112}, {23.15755, 
   53.1271107911688}, {25.49395, 59.0354051335424}, {27.74521, 
   58.0244549818172}, {29.35326, 64.583451422127}, {30.72483, 
   60.3382935190099}, {32.89096, 73.4145923461695}, {34.0166, 
   73.521013149736}}

S = Interpolation[data];

    Data1 = {{0, 0}
  , {1, 41.1557652072566}, {2, 26.7071660139355}, {3, 
   52.5076912302508}, {4, 54.8574199760621}, {5, 
   58.0812755530632}, {6, 18.7154799672259}, {7, 
   55.1908623688319}, {8, 51.5182209503713}, {9, 
   53.0136468565549}, {10, 33.50035387528139}, {11, 
   33.53258650156708}, {12, 33.56151636992248}, {13, 
   72.6412318965037}, {14, 65.2496396332273}, {15, 
   75.7039929579603}, {16, 75.5678903567905}, {17, 
   89.8171235423774}, {18, 48.893863309522}, {19, 
   69.0161541536314}, {20, 102.712926300251}, {21, 
   105.20412918517}, {22, 113.786293961958}, {23, 
   119.154942745288}, {24, 130.32846330578}, {25, 
   114.041282090499}, {26, 109.546865537661}, {27, 
   110.940798932485}, {28, 88.8075898694084}, {29, 
   110.894095083624}, {30, 107.191935220656}, {31, 
   85.3126374855899}, {32, 121.398367136963}, {33, 
   108.281340306189}, {34, 124.438872899984}, {35, 
   138.668283540471}, {36, 115.726426869181}}

GM = Interpolation[Data1];



 Plotresshear2 = 
 Plot[S[z] + (0.00003974057058409937` E^(-0.07243264122733914` z) \
(-317.6971390528727` + 1.` E^(0.14486528245467828` z))*GM[z]*1000*1/(
     5.286*0.305)), {z, 25.595153556674596`, 35.00}, 
  AspectRatio -> 0.6, PlotStyle -> Orange, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, 20], PlotStyle -> Thick, 
  Filling -> Axis, TicksStyle -> Directive["Label", 20], 
  LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 20, GrayLevel[0]}, 
  ImageSize -> Large]

    Labeled[Rotate[
  Show[Plotresshear2, PlotRange -> Automatic, ImageResolution -> 500],
   270 Degree ], {"Depth (m)", "  stresses (kPa)"}, {Left, Top}, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 20, GrayLevel[0]}, 
 RotateLabel -> True]
```

rotate the tick 90 degrees without frame to be parallel with the label 
thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if the following approaches give what you need:

1. Apply rotation to the graphics primitives in `Plotresshear2` (instead of rotating `Plotresshear2`):

```
rotatedplot = MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, RotationTransform[270 Degree]] &, 
    Plotresshear2, {1}];

plot = Show[rotatedplot, AspectRatio -> 1/.6, 
   ImageSize -> {300, Automatic}, PlotRange -> All, 
   Ticks -> {Automatic, Charting`ScaledTicks["Reverse"][##] &}];

Labeled[plot, {"Depth (m)",  "stresses (kPa)"}, {Left, Top}, 
  LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 20, GrayLevel[0]}, 
 RotateLabel -> True, FrameMargins -> {{-50, 0}, {0, 0}}]
```

[image]

2. An alternative approach is to use `ParametricPlot` (instead of `Plot`) with the option `ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Reverse"}` to get the desired rotation directly. We need to use the two-parameter form of `ParametricPlot` to get the filling and one-parameter version to get the line and combine the two with `Show`:

```
pp1 = ParametricPlot[{v (S[z] + (0.00003974057058409937 E^(-0.07243264122733914 z)  
    (-317.6971390528727 + E^(0.14486528245467828 z))*GM[z]*1000*1/(5.286*0.305))), z}, 
   {z, 25.595153556674596, 35.00}, {v, 0, 1},
   BoundaryStyle -> None, PlotStyle -> Orange, 
   PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1/.6,
   Frame -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
   AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, 20], 
   PlotStyle -> Thick, TicksStyle -> Directive["Label", 20], 
   LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 20, GrayLevel[0]}, 
   ImageSize -> {300, Automatic}, 
   ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Reverse"}];

pp2 = ParametricPlot[{S[z] + (0.00003974057058409937 E^(-0.07243264122733914 z) 
      (-317.6971390528727 + E^(0.14486528245467828 z))*GM[z]*1000*1/(5.286*0.305)), z}, 
    {z, 25.595153556674596, 35.00}, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red], 
    ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Reverse"}];

Labeled[Show[pp1, pp2], {"Depth (m)",  "stresses (kPa)"}, {Left, Top}, 
  LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 20, GrayLevel[0]}, 
 RotateLabel -> True,   FrameMargins -> {{-50, 0}, {0, 0}}]
```

[image]

3. Yet another alternative is to have `Frame -> True` and to use `FrameLabel` to place the labels:

```
pp1b = ParametricPlot[{v (S[z] + (0.00003974057058409937 E^(-0.07243264122733914 z)  
    (-317.6971390528727 + E^(0.14486528245467828 z))* GM[z]*1000*1/(5.286*0.305))), z}, 
   {z, 25.595153556674596, 35.00}, {v, 0, 1},
   BoundaryStyle -> None, PlotStyle -> Orange, 
   PlotRange -> {All, {0, -40}}, AspectRatio -> 1/.6,
   Frame -> True, 
   FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, 
      {Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Identity, Identity}][##] &, All}}, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
   FrameLabel -> { {"Depth (m)", None}, {None,  "  stresses (kPa)"}}, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 20], 
   PlotStyle -> Thick, TicksStyle -> Directive["Label", 20], 
   LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 20, 
   GrayLevel[0]}, 
   ImageSize -> {350, Automatic}, 
   ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Reverse"}];


Show[pp1b, pp2]
```

[image]

4. Finally, you can `Show` `Plotresshear2` using custom ticks with labels rotated by `-270 Degree` so that when `Show[...]` is rotated the labels appear aligned with the axes:

```
tickF = Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear"][##] /.
  {a_, b_Integer, c_, d_}:> {a, Rotate[ToString @ b, -270 Degree], c, d}&;

Labeled[Rotate[Show[Plotresshear2, ImageSize -> {500, Automatic}, 
    PlotRange -> All, Ticks -> {tickF, tickF}], 270 Degree ], 
 {"Depth (m)", " stresses (kPa)"}, {Left, Top}, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 20, GrayLevel[0]},
 RotateLabel -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it really works.